# How to create details tag of html5

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

We need to create my own details like html5 tag using html,css,javascript in angular 7. how to do it?

```html
<details>
  <summary>Copyright 1999-2018.</summary>
  <p> - by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  <p>All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.</p>
</details>
```

alternative way of doing this. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

use `document.createElement`.

```js
const details = document.createElement('details');
const p1 = document.createElement('p');
const p2 = document.createElement('p');

p1.textContent = '- by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.';
p2.textContent = 'All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.';

details.appendChild(p1);
details.appendChild(p2);
document.body.appendChild(details);
```

Comment: I don't like this, we're talking angular here and you're throwing all this low level element creation and appending, I don't think it's either necessary or viable.

Comment: I don't like this, we're talking angular here and you're throwing all this low level element creation and appending, I don't think it's either necessary or viable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle method on click event to show and hide details content. 
This link is Angular 7 example, like your html details:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-avnuk6?file=src/app/app.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let event of events;" class="event-list">

    <section class="event-item" (click)="event.toggle=!event.toggle">
        <div class="event-summary">
            <summary class="event-name">{{ event.name }} </summary>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- WANT TO SHOW THIS WHEN ABOVE SECTION ELEMENT IS CLICKED -->
    <section class="event-details" *ngIf="event.toggle">
    <p> - by Refsnes Data. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  <p>All content and graphics on this web site are the property of the company Refsnes Data.</p>
    </section>
    <!-- END SECTION -->

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

when you create a component with the angular cli, the name you will call it will be the name of your tag, but it will show as 'app-detail'. To change this, in the component decorator in the voice 'selector' you can change it as you please